# How can I live in a large house and not have high utility bills?

Tags: hvac

I would like to buy a five bedroom house in Illinois, mainly because I love the property. I wish the house was smaller, because I would be the only one living there. My plan would be to live in only a small portion of it, but how could the utility bills be low? It would need to be weatherized, but is there a way to heat just a small portion of the house without the pipes bursting in the winter?

Comment: How much work and capital do you want to invest in this house?

Comment: Also yes -- what do you have for a heating system in the house, and how well is it insulated and air sealed at present? (See if you can get a blower door test run as part of the inspection before you buy it)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It's forced air. I haven't decided how much work & capital I want to put into it, but don't want to be inundated with bills. The utility bills right now are through the roof, but there are a lot of cracks that can be sealed up. In the winter, you can feel cold air blowing from under the front door. Thanks for the advice. Property taxes are $27K/yr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the existing insulation and heating system - depending on whether it's forced hot air, hot water radiators, steam radiators, or baseboard electric, it may be difficult to turn off the heat in unused rooms.

With baseboard electric, it's usually pretty easy - there's usually a thermostat in every room, essentially every room is it's own zone, you can turn it down or off as easily as turning a dial.  With steam and hot water, it really depends on how the zones are loops are laid out, but it's often doable with steam.

Protecting the pipes depends on the plumbing layout.  You have to be particularly careful where pipes are in outside walls, and how the outside walls are insulated.  It may be that you have to use heat tape and / or insulate those pipes to prevent freezing.

You probably don't want to let the temperature in the unused part of the house go too low for various reasons.  Properties that are used seasonally (vacation homes, etc.) have lots of issues that come from freezing and thawing etc. - condensation, cracks in the finishes, etc. etc.

No matter what you do, you can't change some factors - you still have more surface area, a larger system to maintain, etc., so costs are still going to be higher than a small house.

Comment: The Dept. of Energy puts out a “pie-chart” that shows where a typical family spends their energy costs. The chart shows about 60% - 65% goes towards heating/cooling. Another 20% - 25% goes towards hot water heating. The rest is lights, etc. So, if you’re going to spend money to save energy, guess what you should attack first? Focus on quick paybacks like: 1) attic insulation, 2) wall insulation, 3) air filters, 4) full load washer/dishwasher

Comment: batsplatsterson Thanks a lot! It's forced hot air.

Answer (score 1):

Good insulation, double glazing, air conditioning used with care (-8°C difference from outside is enough in summer, 20°C is ok in winter), class A++ electric appliance, gas tankless water heater, led lighting.

Comment: And don't forget the air sealing to go with that insulation!